# Calculating the residue of given quantity

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, residue-calculus, riemann-zeta

The attached paper claims on top of page 4 that

\begin{align}
Res(\zeta^2(s)\prod_{p|d}(1-p^{-s})^2\frac{x^{s-1}}{s}; s=1) = \frac{\varphi^2(d)}{d^2}(\log{x}+2\gamma-1)-\frac{2\varphi(d)}{d}\sum_{\delta|d}\frac{\mu(\delta)\log{\delta}}{\delta}
\end{align}

Could someone help me with the proof? I tried the proof for few specific $d's$ and was able to see the relation, but could not see how $\varphi$ and sum over divisors come up for general $d$.

http://math.bu.edu/keio2019/talks/Nguyen.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant $$\prod_{p|d}(1-p^{-s})^2$$ What is the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)^2$ at $s=1$ ? And that of $F(s)=\frac{x^{s-1}}{s}\prod_{p|d}(1-p^{-s})^2$ ? Thus what is the coef of $(s-1)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of $\zeta(s)^2F(s)$ ?

Comment: I am having trouble getting the Laurent expansion of $$\prod_{p|d}(1-p^{-s})^2$$

Comment: $F(s)=F(1)+F'(1)(s-1)+O((s-1)^2)$